# Equivalent definitions of independent random variables in "A Course in Probability Theory"

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, independence

In page 53 of Kai Lai Chung's "A Course in Probability Theory", the author says:

> The following two formulas below are equivalent
> $$
> P\left\{\bigcap_{j=1}^n\left(X_j \in B_j\right)\right\}=\prod_{i=1}^n P\left(X_j \in B_j\right)\text{ for any linear Borel sets ${B_j, 1\leq j \leq n}$}
> $$
> $$ \iff$$
> $$
> P\left\{ \bigcap_{j=1}^n\left(X_j\leq x_j\right)\right\} =\prod_{j=1}^n P\left(X_j \leq x_j \right)\text{ for any $x_j, 1 \leq j \leq n \in \mathrm{R}$}
> $$

---

My train of thought to prove this claim is as follows.

For fixed $ x_j, 1\leq j \leq n-1$, consider $$G := \left\{ A \in 2^R | P\left\{ \bigcap_{j=1}^{n-1}\left(X_j\leq x_j\right)\cap (X_n \in A)\right\} =\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} P\left(X_j \leq x_j \right)* P(X_n \in A)\right\}$$ I want to prove that G is a $\sigma $-algebra. A queation occurs when I was trying to verify that $G$ is closed under finite interception, i.e. $A_1, A_2 \in G \implies A_1 \cap A_2 \in G$.

And it seems unsovable.

Comment: You have to apply the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem.

Comment: Thanks very much! But I'm wondering if there's any elementary method?

Comment: You cannot prove this from definition of $\sigma-$ algebra generated by a class. You need some theorm for this.

Comment: Useful theorem! Thanks again.